# Is it ok to build a logo quiz app with Phonegap using multiple pages?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova

I want to create an app that runs on iOS and Android using Phonegap. 
I have the web app working properly on my desktop browser, my only concern is regarding the page where user has to guess the logo and submits his answer. 
Actually, I've made separate page for each logo, so I ended up having more than 200 pages. 
Will I encounter any issue with phonegap while "compiling the app", or should I use a template page, to load data dynamically based on questions ID's ?

Also, I am storing the user's answers with localStorage, will the data be saved forever when the app will be running on a mobile device ? Or should I do it differently ?

Comment: you should load the data dynamically from a database which will also answer your last question about localStorage. Save it to a database instead.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer man. Could you please advice me about what kind of database should I be using while building with Phonegap ?

Comment: well phonegap is just an html/css/js compiler so you can use ajax to send get/post requests to a database. You can use MySql as your database

Comment: As for as phonegap compiling issue, I don't think there will be any issue. But yes, as Jmore suggested the recommended approach is use database. regarding local storage, yes data will be saved unless and until user will delete data from manage app settings.

Comment: Thanks for both of you for your feedbacks.